# How to use FadeInAnimation.class in UWP programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, fadein

I'm trying to do a simple fade in animation programmatically. 
In XAML, I have a page with a named Grid inside.

The code behind looks like this:

```
InitializeComponent();
Button button = new Button() {
    Width = 200,
    Height = 200,
    Content = "Text",
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
};
button.Name = "target";

Storyboard myStory = new Storyboard();
FadeInThemeAnimation animation = new FadeInThemeAnimation() {
    BeginTime = new TimeSpan(2),
    Duration = new TimeSpan(4),
};

animation.TargetName = button.Name;
Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, button);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, button.Name);

myStory.Children.Add(animation);
myGrid.Children.Add(button);

button.PointerEntered += (s, e) => {
    myStory.Begin();
};
```

The problem is that I don't see any animation. Also, I'm not sure where to call `begin()`. Is it best to place in the `Loaded` event or somehwere else?

Edit: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.FadeInThemeAnimation) is the FadeInThemeAnimation that I'm trying to use.

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: @kennyzx I don't see any fade animation. Also, I'm not sure where to call story.Begin() and if the binding is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code.

**Firstly,** in the official doc, `FadeInThemeAnimation` is described as

> preconfigured opacity animation

So, it should increase the `Opacity` of an `UIElement` to 1.0 or something like that. But, I  believe that the `Button` you are targeting for the animation already has an opacity 1.0. So, you won't see any change even if the animation is working. So, try a `FadeOutThemeTransition` instead to test whether your code works or not.

**Secondly,** you do not set all these things to set the target :

`SetTarget`, `SetTargetName` or `animation.TargetName =`

You just use one of them.

**Thirdly,** You do not set the `Duration` property with a `new TimeSpan(4)`. I don't know what type of `TimeSpan` is returned by the constructor you used, but it doesn' work with that, it works with something like `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)`.

**Fourthly,** what are you trying to do with that `BeginTime` property of `FadInThemeAnimation`? Even if you are using it on intention, the `TimeSpan` problem also applies here.

So, after all of that, try something like this:

```
Storyboard myStory = new Storyboard();
FadeOutThemeAnimation animation = new FadeOutThemeAnimation()
{
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)
};

Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, button);

myStory.Children.Add(animation);
PlayGround.PointerPressed += (kk, kkk) => myStory.Begin();
```

I've tested it, it works. Hope that helps.

Comment: Much appreciated! I also checked the `TimeSpan` constructor and the unit is _tick_ which is 100 nanoseconds. So I think that the timespan would have been way too short to see anyway. Thanks again for the help!